# Python immutable function parameter

Tags: python, object, variable-assignment

I'm trying to understand the core ideas of Python and I've come across to a nice article that explains passing the parameter reference to an object. For instance;

```
def add_to_list(list_to_add, value):
  list_to_add.append(value)
```

**will** be able to change the original list_to_add parameter while;

```
def change_list(list_to_add):
  list_to_add = [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

**won't** do anything.

I am currently writing a basic linked list print function where it is simply like;

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val, next=None):
    self.val = val
    self.next = next

root = Node(2, Node(3, Node(4, Node(5, Node(6)))))

def print_list(root):
  while root:
    print root.val,
    root = root.next
  print ''
```

And you've guessed it right. It didn't change the root's value. Now my question is **how come this happens**. Is it because the python classes are immutable?

Answer (score 4):

Python classes certainly aren't immutable. You can change them pretty much as you like (with some corner-cases involving either extension types or **slots**).

However, what you do here is you define a module-level (global) variable root, and then a parameter-name root within print_list.

Invoking print_list(root) and then assigning something to root will *NOT* change the module-level global!

If you want that (you shouldn't want that, but that's a different discussion about avoiding global variables), you'd have to declare root inside print_list to be global

```
def print_list():
    global root
    ...
```

And then you don't need the parameter.

*AGAIN*: Don't do this!!!

If you'd used a tool like pylint to check your code, it should have warned you that the parameter name "root" shadows a module-global name "root".

Comment: Thank you so much for your descriptive answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple:

```
obj.do_something()
```

operates on the passed object, possibly modifying it (such as `list_to_add.append()`), while

```
obj = something_other
```

discards the reference to the old object and uses a different one.

Changes on an object will (of course) be visible to "other" users of the object, while a re-assignment only affects the place where it is redefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution